# How can I stash my changes and go back to my last check-in in Git?

Tags: git, git-stash

The story goes like so:

I branched my repo to try and do some changes to the way my wcf stuff works.
I checked in my changes to my new branch a day ago when everything was dandy before I started to get a bit weird with wcf. I then started trying out some stuff that hasn't really worked out, though I think i'm on the right track.

Now I don't have time to keep trying this so I'd like to go back to my last checkin but I don't want to lose this stuff forever. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stash it (using `git stash`) in which case your working directory will be reset to your last checkin (ie. to your HEAD).

Or you can branch your current branch to a new branch, and then commit your changes there.  I prefer to use branches to stashes when possible, I see stashes as a much more temporary/transient tool.

Comment: so when i go git branch newbranch - it will copy all the chamges to that branch, then git checkout originalbranch i go back to the last checkin?

Comment: @cvista: `git branch` just creates a branch. It doesn't commit anything. If you want to save away your modifications, you need to create and check out that new branch then commit to it: `git checkout -b newbranch; git add ...; git commit`. *Then* you can safely switch to a different branch.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest quickly putting your work on another branch:

```
git stash
git checkout -b new-branch-name
git stash apply
git commit -a -m "commit message here"
git checkout current-branch-name
```

You could do just the `git stash` part, but then your stuff will be in the monolithic stash stack forever. Better to put it somewhere that you can find it again, since you'll need the stash queue for other things later.

Comment: brilliant :) both right tho... arrr [why can't we mark more than one answer as correct?!]

Comment: The stash is *completely* unnecessary here. Creating and checking out a branch at the current commit will always succeed. And worse, you've left out the important step: there should be a `git commit` before switching branches back!

Comment: Doh, you're totally right -- I did miss the commit. Fixed. I also agree that the stash is usually unnecessary, but I've also encountered some weird edge cases where it can matter, and since it will hardly hurt, I'll leave it.